# Morph targets: A sphere shape turning into a cylindrical unwrapped sphere shape

Tags: modifiers, uv

I'd like to do an animation where a globe will unwrap it's texture.

Go from this

[image: 3d sphere]

to this

[image: flattened sphere]

, but in 3D space, so it will look exactly as its unwrapped form.

The only methods I have on mind are extremely tedious, anyone there more clever than I care to give a hint on how to achieve the effect?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do this backwards.

Crate a plane, enter edit mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and subdivide it.

Press (<kbd>U</kbd>) and select **Unwrap** to create a UV map.

[image]

Exit edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> and in the properties panel create two shape keys by pressing the + box **TWICE**.That will create a base shape key for the plane and one for the deformed plane (a sphere).

[image]

Back in edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>, rotate the plane 90 degrees in the Z axis <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>

Then rotate 90 degrees in X <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
[image]

Move the plane up on the Y axis (this distance will be the radius of the sphere)
[image]

Press <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> type **warp** and select it.
On the warp settings change the **WarpAngle** to 180 degrees
[image][image][image]

Rotate the plane 90 degrees in the Y axis <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>9</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and warp again. This time make **change the WarpAngle to 360** degrees.

[image][image]

At this point you should have a **SPHERE**!!
[image]

When you switch back to **Object Mode** your sphere will go back to a flat plane, don't worry you can control (and animate) the transformation by moving the **value** slider on the **Shape Keys**.
[image]

[image][image]

Then you can use UVs as the texture's coordinates in a material.

[image]

Comment: If you want to keep only the final mesh - you can follow these instructions. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/how-to-apply-shape-keys

Comment: Afterwards, you might want to check the normals are facing the correct way - mine weren't, and I had very interesting effects when I imported the blend file into Unity.

Comment: The second warp needs to be -360 degrees to avoid the map coming out reversed like in the question's anti-Earth.

Comment: Can't find warp settings in more recent blender... the warp modifier doesn't half those settings..

Answer (score 5):

A simple script which transforms vertices to their uv-coordinates (does not rip the geometry!):

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.active_object
mesh = obj.data
uv = mesh.uv_layers.active
shape_key = mesh.shape_keys.key_blocks[obj.active_shape_key_index]

for index, loop in enumerate(uv.data):
    vertex = shape_key.data[mesh.loops[index].vertex_index]
    vertex.co = Vector((loop.uv.x, loop.uv.y, 0.0))
```

You can rip the geometry manually:

- In the UV Editor select an island and run `Seams From Island`.
- Select a seam edge and press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> -> Seam, to select all seams.
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> -> Edge Split.

Comment: Thank you for that, interesting how you provided an answer to do the task through scripting and @cegaton to do so visually.

Comment: This script allow one to do crazy deformation magic and should be included as an add-on.