# Texturing a sphere mesh?

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

If I had a map of the world or drew my own map texture how would I use it as a texture for a sphere mesh, and also how would I do this without an ugly seem on the part of the sphere? I want texture a sphere.

Comment: Here's one way: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Comment: read also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13927/1853