# Map equirectangular image to sphere?

Tags: rendering, texturing

Can I map a 360° panorama as equirectangular image to a sphere, so that it resembles the original panorama inside out?

Comment: Do you want this as an actual mesh, or can it be just the background world texture? Because it is relatively easy to setup a world texture.

Comment: I want it *on* a mesh.

Comment: Go into edit mode, press `A` to select all, press `U` > Sphere Projection. You should have a reasonably accurate UV you can edit. In the UV Image Editor, select the desired texture and edit as desired.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere and this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/morph-targets-a-sphere-shape-turning-into-a-cylindrical-unwrapped-sphere-shape

Comment: Yes, UV mapping seems to be what I need. Just tried that in another 3D software (don't have Blender installed here).