# How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere

Tags: modeling, animation, workflow

How to make a grid-to-sphere animation like this?

[image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13927/1853

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Comment: Thanks cegaton, but shape key is linear deformation. Obviously my case isn't. I mean, each vertex doesn't move along a straight line.

Comment: Unbelievably stupid that blender doesn't just have the coding to do this automatically when applying an image to a sphere...

Comment: @reee What are you talking about? The question is not about having a sphere object and projecting an image onto it, this is about having a plane object and converting it into a sphere by a kind of "curling up" animation.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think the one who made that reference GIF (in another software) used two **Simple Deform** modifiers:

1. Create a plane, switch to Edit mode, <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>. then use a loop cut to divide it into two squares, then subdivide;
2. Add a **Simple Deform** modifier, set deform method to *Bend*, use a new empty object as its origin, select the empty, then <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>. (to bend it along an expected Z axis)
3. Add another **Simple Deform** modifier, also set deform method to *Bend*, use a second empty object as the origin, select the empty, then <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>90</kbd>.
4. At frame 1, set 0 as the *Angle* value for both Bend modifiers, insert keyframe for them. Then jump to, say, frame 60, set 180 for the first Angle, 360 for the second Angle (for 360, you may have to type on keyboard), again, intert keyframe for both.
5. If normal direction is incorrect, flip it in Edit Mode.

[image]

[image]

---

UPDATE: In the incoming v2.8, the Simple Deform modifer has a new option that allows choosing Local Axis, so you can use only one Empty in this case, like this:
[image]

Comment: Nicely optimized! This is better than raising it with the shape-key, those bend origins are very nice.

Comment: Exactly how do you make the GIFs? I want to be able to answer questions more efficiently and I have no idea how to make a GIF.

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist you can use GifCam

Comment: (for new users) the Bend modifier is a mode within the **Simple Deform Modifier**

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist you can use screen capture like: http://www.cockos.com/licecap/

Comment: @TheMinecrafterandBlendmist I tried almost all of them and the best was ScreenToGif 1.4

Comment: You are an endless source of useful information. I'd upvote this one twice if I could.

Comment: If the plane is not bending correctly (or overlapping itself), you may need to reverse the values (180° in X and 360° in Z). Thanks, Leon Cheung for this great tip!

Comment: Also, add a "Weld" modifier last in the stack to remove double vertices at the seam. :-)

Answer (score 20):

1. Add an **UV Sphere**, you can use any segments and rings counts (memorize segments). Then rotate it -90d in Y and translate it +1.0 in Z. Adjust the spheres origin to [0,0,0] with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *To Center* and *Object > Transform > Origin To 3D Cursor*. Important is to not change the scale and have the sphere with radius of 1.0:

   [image]
2. In edit-mode **delete almost all of the vertices** but leave the most bottom "[meridian](http://img.tfd.com/hm/JPG/A5meridian.jpg)". Extrude the mesh in Y direction to a distance of 3.142 with <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> + *3.142*. Subtract 2 from your segment count and divide by 2, add that many loopcuts ((32 - 2) / 2 = 15 for me):

   [image]
3. **Create a shapekey**. Switch to 3D Cursor Pivot point and scale the mesh down to 0 in local X axis (hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>). Animate this shapekey from value 1.0 to 0.0:

   [image]
4. Add a **Simple Deform Bend** modifier. Add an Empty as *Origin* to control the direction of bending. Rotate the empty 90d in X, -90d in Z.

   [image]
5. **Animate** the modifier's **angle** from 0d to 180d. Duplicate the mesh and scale it -1.0 in Y. Tadaa!

   [image]
6. Edit: Oh and the Bend modifier can be animated to 360d, so you can extrude the mesh in 3rd step both ways and have the whole thing in 1 piece, no need to duplicate and flip..

Comment: Shapekey is good, just the initial grid seems not evenly distributed?