# How to add duplicate units of a mesh to unwrapped UV sphere

Tags: mesh, uv, vertices

Hi I am trying to insert the ico-sphere seen in the picture (gray colour, unselected) to each vertex of the UV sphere that is unwrapped, and then finally make an animation to wrap the UV sphere with the icospheres in the vertex attached.

I wish to use the duplivert function to insert my icoshphere in the vertex and animate the plain into a sphere. May be I am not starting from the right point?

Is it possible? Thanks in advance for you help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what you want to achieve could you clarify the animation part?

UV unwrapping is made for the purpose of texturing alone, no geometry animation is possible through unwrapping.

Do you wish to make some sort of morphing animation transitioning from the plane shape into a sphere shape?

For the duplication part try looking into dupliverts here https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/duplication/dupliverts.html

Comment: Yes, I wish to use the duplivert function to insert my icoshphere in the vertex and animate the plain into a sphere. May be I am not starting from the right point?

Comment: the plane you see in the image editor is not a plane, it's the sphere unwrapped for texturing. You can't use it to animate something like plane to sphere. check [How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053/11431)

Comment: Yes, UV is not suited for shape animations, you probably started on the wrong foot. Check the link provided by Bithur, that is probably the correct way to achieve what you want.