# Map Nasa Heightmap to Sphere

Tags: height-map

I'm pretty new to Blender and I'm trying to map a [Nasa Heigtmap](http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/73000/73934/gebco_08_rev_elev_21600x10800.png) onto a sphere. I've tried to use the Displace Modifier but the heightmap is streched: [image]
I think this is because Africa is at the UV spheres pole, but I have no idea how to change that.

Help would be very appreciated!

Comment: The best way to deal with this, in my opinion, is not to use a UV sphere, but to deform a plane to become a sphere, that way you can map the image correctly without having deformation at the poles. See this answer: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053'

Comment: try to using microdisplacement

Comment: It should also be noted that the earth is so ridiculously big that any mountains are pretty much neglicible compared to the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. 1. Apply scale and rotation of the object. Activate the object than press Ctrl + A button, than choose scale and rotation. 2. Unwrap the object perfectly to a rectangular shape. Delete top and bottom vertices. than make one vertical markseam, than unwrap the sphere. please learn how to unwrap UV sphere, in somewhere tutorial. 3. add more polygon, increase subdivision surface to highest level. if needed add double subdivision surface modifier, more polygon more detai.