# How do you deform a flat model (In my case, a woven metal mesh), into a dome?

Tags: transforms

I am new to blender, and therefore, still navigating through its options. However, I still have not come across a method to perform what I need but I'm sure its a very simple solution.

I'm using blender, because if I attempt this on SolidWorks my computer crashes.
I have a flat circular woven metal mesh part/object and I wish to deform this object in the middle into a dome shape. To resemble like a microphone head mesh dome, but then down into a cylinder sides.

Is there a function that I can deform a flat surface, by a certain radius, into a dome structure?

Thanks for the help

Regards
Scott

Comment: Try poportional editing with "sphere" as fallof, scrolling the mousewheel while editing you can change the influence radius

Comment: first question is woven metal made by texture or mesh?
some screenshots of your workflow are welcome

Comment: This might be a solution for the spherical top and cylindrical sides - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74614/bend-flat-circular-object-into-half-sphere/74639#74639