# Bug with Apply Modifier ( Simple Deform) as Shape Key?

Tags: animation, modifiers, shape-keys

I create an animation with a plane is transforming to a sphere by using the method describing by @leon-cheung in [this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere) .

[image]

I want to apply the two modifiers (Bend in Simple Deform) as shape key but the result is not indentic.

[image]

It seems that it is the second modifier which is the problem.

There are no problem if I use only one modifier with an angle less than 180° .

Is there a way to have the same result (animation transforming plane to sphere ) by using shape keys ?

Thank you.