# How to bake 2 Simple Deform modifiers in Shape Keys

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, unity, shape-keys

I need to transfer this amasing plane-to-sphere effect (from this question [How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere)) to Unity.

Therefore I need to bake 2 Simple Deform Modifiers into shapekeys. The problem is that in this case instead of sphere I get some strange distorted shape:

[image]

How can I Bake 2 modifiers into shapekeys (or keyframes) while keeping the same effect?