# How to create rounded shape of the grill?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

Hello and best regards to everyone viewing this post!

I am quite new to 3d art and blender in particular, so seeking for some help out here. 
I am creating a 3d model of B&W 803 D3 speaker The problem is that I can't really create a rounded shape for the grill. I've created grill itself by using mirror modifier and a couple of arrays. Then I added lattice and bent it with proportional falloff. however disadvantage is corners of the grill which are sticking out of the body of twitter itself. 
question is: is there any other way to bend it properly? or some other approaches? 
[image: grill problem]
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: That is how I would go about it. Another way would be to use the Shrinkwrap modifier and a target Sphere. Use the Project mode.

Comment: Shrinkwrap will stretch the holes in the mesh, which is unwanted. And the Lattice method is not precise. It needs to be bent. Look at [morphing a plane into a sphere here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere). Then use Boolean modifier to cut only a section out of it.