# How do I UV unwrap a half sphere?

Tags: uv

[image: Uv Unwrapping, Smart UV project function]

[image: Ladybug Template]

[image: Ladybug distortion of image]

Hello, I am a beginner in Blender and I have tried to make a ladybug for my project. I managed to model it, but now I have to add a ladybug texture to it. I heard that by using the "Smart UV Project" function, I can easily   add my Ladybug pattern to it. However, after doing this, my image started to distort. Now as you can see, the ladybug's patterns has gone really wrong and I don't know how to fix it, so is there any way I can fix this problem and make my ladybug work?

Comment: You have a lot of polygons there! That's going to make UV unwrapping a little harder. Try opening your texture image in your UV/Image editor viewport (Image->Open Image), and it will show you how your geometry lines up with the picture. Then you can move those verts around to change how the image lines up with the model. You can also export the UV layout to an image (UVs->Exoprt UV Layout) - this gives you a pattern to draw your texture over, like a coloring book.

Answer (score 1):

It will be hard to have perfect circles on your ladybug this way. You could do it several other ways, but here are 3 ways to do it:

**1) DIRECT PAINTING**

- Unwrap your semi-sphere in Blender.
- Prepare a red image texture in the *UV/Image Editor*
- Plug the *Image Texture* node with your image in a *Diffuse* (and plug the *Diffuse* in the *Output*).
- In the *3D View* window, switch to *Texture Paint* mode and paint your black dots with a very steep curve brush.

[image]

**2) PAINT A MASK**

- Unwrap your semi-sphere in Blender.
- Create a 100% white texture and plug it in a *Diffuse* (and plug the *Diffuse* in the *Output*).
- In the *3D View* window, switch to *Texture Paint* mode and paint your black dots with a very steep curve brush.
- Now change your node organization and use your texture as a factor in a mix between 2 *Diffuse* nodes: one black and one red.

[image]

**3) TRANSFORM A PLANE INTO A SPHERE**

You could also create a plane, map your pattern on it, transform it into a sphere with some *Simple Deform* modifiers / *Bend* mode, then cut the sphere in half: [How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053)

Comment: yes you're right, I'm going to edit  ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Use the primitive's default UV map**

It looks like it might not take too long to remodel your bug...

When a new primitive is added there is the option to create the default UV map.

[image]

Then tab into edit mode and selecting all, switching to UV editor layout

[image]

This was a really quick effort, with all the UV selected and scaled by eye to match the texture image as in question. (eg without rotating image lol)

The nature of the default mapping is equirectangular  360 degrees longitude "U" by 180 degrees latitude (2 x 1) "V".  Will be best at the equator and worst at the poles.

[image]
*Image from the wiki [Equirectangular Projection.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) showing how dots are distorted toward the pole.*

[image]
*as an image to default UVMap, see how they are now all dots*

A black line across top of image would translate to black dot on pole, similarly to how (ant)arctic circles appear across the top and bottom of world map

For half a sphere, delete a half of sphere.