# How to map an equirectangular image onto an icosphere in Blender 2.79b

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I'm new to Blender 2.79. I'm trying to map an equirectangular image of the night sky (pictured below) onto an icosphere.

[image: starmap equirectangular]

The problem is, every time I manage to create a material and/or texture for the icosphere, it wraps only part of the way around the object. Pictured below is as far as I can get, with a color-inverted version of the texture so you can see better what's going on.

[image: screencap 1]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you could correctly unwrap an icosphere but you could do it another way around with an UV sphere, an icosphere, and a *Shrinkwrap* modifier:

- Create an UV sphere.
- Select all except the two poles and *Unwrap* > *Sphere Projection* mode, with *Align to Object* option.
- Select the 2 poles and make a simple unwrap.
- Prepare your material.
- It works, your drawing is projected on your UV sphere.
- In *Object* mode, create an icosphere within your UV sphere.
- Give your UV sphere a *Shrinkwrap* modifier and choose the icosphere as *Target*.
- Give your UV sphere one or probably 2 *Subsurf* modifiers, one above, one below the *Shrinkwrap* modifier. Test the best solution, and the best *Subdivision* values, it looks like an amount of 3 is necessary on the top *Subsurf*.
- Now, thanks to the *Shrinkwrap*, your UV sphere has taken the shape of the icosphere, you should have the result you want.

[image]

Comment: this is an awesome work around, thank you! do you know of a way I can map the UV directly as an equirectangular projection? your method distorts the poles.

Comment: maybe in the UV Editor you could try to move the UV top and bottom edges a bit, with the proportional editing enabled? or maybe try this method: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053   I don't know if it will fix the problem...

Comment: If you remove the poles of a UV sphere, add a longitudinal seam, and unwrap with 'spherical projection' from an  orthogonal view,  poles top and bottom, you don't need the add-on. But I've been struggling to find a way to bake from the sphere to the geodesic, without discontinuity across the geodesic's edges.. tried a lot of things.. cages.. subdividing, including UV's at various stages.. no luck yet...

Comment: ok my bad, I've edited, no need for UV square addon actually   ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

All you need is use **Environmental** texture node for image.

All credits goes to [lemon (original post)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/167445/2214).

Answer (score 0):

I think you still have the light set as a point, which will only illuminate a certain area of the object facing the point.

Change the material to shadeless or add some hemi lamps to illuminate more of your object so you can see if your problem really does exist.