# Export model with Enviroment Texture and Texture coordinate

Tags: texturing, materials, export, gltf

I have built a simple model where I project an equirectangular image to a mesh using an environment texture. Sometimes the image is not centered correctly so I do this by linking the image location to another mesh using a texture coordinate node (which fixes the distortion). The setup in the material tab is shown here

[image: Image showing the setup of the material tab]

My challenge comes in exporting this in a format that I could use in a web browser. I have tried to export to glTF but the material is not exported with the model.

I tried an alternative method using an image texture instead and this material does get exported but the texture coordinates are still lost and so the material maps incorrectly.

Has anyone had success in exporting this setup before?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using UV Mapping on an Equirectangular Projection](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167968/using-uv-mapping-on-an-equirectangular-projection)