# Why is my road offset from it's parent bezier (wrapped to a sphere)?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, shrinkwrap

I'm currently combining [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXldgzeuj1k) with [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053) in an attempt to make something like this:
[image]
Instead, I'm getting something like this:
[image]
I'm using two simple deforms in order to turn the bezier into something like a sphere, then shrinkwrapping it to a UV Sphere in order to make it more rounded and avoid weird twists inward.

Unfortunately, the road array is going a bit crazy. Can anybody tell me how to get it to more closely follow the curve (in a sphere shape)?

Thanks in advance,

--Rev

PS: Shrinkwrapping the road just results in the road losing geometric detail as it's smooshed into a razor thin coating on the sphere.

EDIT / ADDITION:

Just to try and clarify, ultimately I'm looking to have a road layout similar to the following wrapped around the sphere seamlessly.
[image: InterchangeExample01]
[image: InterchangeExample02]

As mentioned below, I'd like to be able to have multiple roads and intersections connecting to each other and looping over and around each other with interchanges, etc

[image]

Comment: instead of a Simple Deform modifier, why don't you use a Curve modifier after the Array? Use a circle as object

Comment: Hi @moonboots! I've tried using a couple of circles to do the job on the road (after the array modifier and the curve modifier for the road layout), and then tried applying the circles and curve modifiers to the bezier curve, but I'm not getting anything that looks like the desired effect above. Every one of the deformation axis ends up just throwing the road geo around crazily. Could you clarify, or give me an example? Thank you!

Comment: do you need one unique road (i.e. one unique curve) or can you just fake it with several circles?

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to be able to have multiple roads and intersections connecting to each other and looping over and around each other with interchanges, etc.

So basically I need the full-fat wrapping of my layout to a cube.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need one unique road?

If that's the case, you could create a sphere, a curve, and use the *Snap* option to stick the curve to the surface of the sphere, then gradually scale down the sphere so that the curve also scales down.

If you don't absolutely need one unique road (which in my opinion is the case in this picture) you could fake this kind of object this way:

- Create your road segment, apply the scale and the rotation, give it an image texture.

[image]

- Create a curve. Give your road segment an *Array* modifier, *Fit Type > Fit Curve*, and a *Curve* modifier.

[image]

- Duplicate your curve + object, rotate and move it as you like, scale the curve (and only the curve).

[image]

Comment: That's very kind of you to provide such a detailed and illustrated answer, @Moonboots! I'll vote it up, but unfortunately this doesn't cover what I'm looking for. I'll try to better explain my target in my question, but ultimately the best illustration of what I want would be... the illustration I'm trying to make... =/