# How can I turn all the normals of this bezier to face outwards from the sphere?

Tags: modifiers, normals, bezier-curves

I’m currently combining [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXldgzeuj1k) with [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053) in an attempt to make a sphere of roads extruded along a bezier. The following is my current effort (**file link below**):
[image]
Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the roads to all face outwards - the beziers are being bent somewhat randomly. I've been pointed in the direction of [this control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c7FmZQaQ568), but unfortunately I'd need to apply all my modifiers and then change the direction of the bezier control points independently - which obviously slows iteration to a crawl.

Can anybody suggest how I could get all the bezier control normals to face outwards?

[image]

Comment: This is probably easy to do with a python script, but I don't know of any builtin way to do it