# Making a pineapple

Tags: modeling

Do you guys know any good ways of making a pineapple in Blender? It can be low poly and cartoonish. So far THIS is best i got
[image]

Comment: LowRes https://identity.trimble.com/commonauth MidRes https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-max-model-pineapple/741563 HiRes https://www.the-boundarystore.com/products/pineapple

Comment: Way better I could do it. Why don't you like your result?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

So... hi poly.

[image]

The leaves are done with an array modifier driven by an empty a bit scaled down, rotated and shifted down.

[image]

The body is an hexagon inside of which the pineapple skin is modeled. It is a bit stretched as will need to make it more oblong later.

Then use 3 arrays to have an hexagonal map:

[image]

Now we need to make that spherical, and we can use [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053/19156) to do it.

This is two simple deforms and a lattice to make it more tubular/oblong:

[image]

[image]

The sequence of modifiers:

[image]

PS: I know there is a gap at the edges of the second simple deform modifier. That will be possible to join it with the weld modifier in 2.83, using a vertex group. For now in 2.82 the weld modifier does not take the vertex group into account.

Comment: Can you describe the process of making the hexagon? Or point me to a link?

Comment: @Strawberry, to make a base hexagon, just add a circle and change its vertices to 6. From that here i've simply extruded and scaled down.

Comment: I get that part; it's what happens next that I'm struggling with! Ah, extruded and scaled down - let me try that

Comment: The best to see what is happening (from the blend file in the answer) is to disable all the modifiers (disable, not remove) then reactivate them one by one (like in the gif above). So you can see how it works step by step.

Answer (score 26):

### Low Poly

[image]

- add *Cylinder*
- in edit mode Loop Cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- search *Un-Subdive* > 1
- *Scale* down top and bottom part to shape oval

[image]

- *Triangulate* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> (but not necessary), for horiyontal split I scale it verticaly so blender use the shorter (horizontal) direction between vertices
- for leaves - *Extrude* <kbd>E</kbd> / *Scale* <kbd>S</kbd> top vertices, *Subdivide* <kbd>W</kbd> and *Scale* down

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's actually quite a cute pineapple. But I have one question: If I look at it from the top or bottom, what will I see? Will the top just be green or the pineapple color? And the bottom? Is it just a pineapple-color "base"?

Comment: You will see what you make :) Yes I could left it filled and extrude, it make more sence - manifold mesh. It was just a quick test, I did not expect such interest on this topic.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand your comment. Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: WORK IS REALLY AWESOME DUDE

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I dont understand your Q. It depend on you, how you will model your. Now there is a hole (because I delete top face as you can see), but you can keep top face when extruding "green" so like that it stay green from top, that is more natural.