# how to fix top faces of Sphere?

Tags: interface, vertices, subdivision-surface

When i add Modifier "subdivision surface" it will happen.Don't know why..

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 1):

There is a few things you can do.

When you subdivide cube you actually gets a sphere with different topology.
[image: Cube subD]
Or you can delete the top polygons and grid-fill them, but that needs some tweaking as the grid-fill will be flat, so you can select the center vertex and with the proportional editing and move him little up so the sphere is round.
[image: gridfill]

Also you can use ISO sphere in the mesh menu but that is made out of tris polygons.

Answer (score 0):

This problem on the surface (when using a Subdivision Surface modifier) is caused by the triangular faces on the top.

### SOLUTION 1 - SUBDIVIDING BEFORE

When you create the sphere, increase the *Segments* and *Rings* in the Redo Panel (on the bottom-left corner of the screen).
[image]

### SOLUTION 2 (recommended) - TRANSFORM TRIANGLES IN QUADS

Select the top vertex.
[image]

Move the cursor on the vertex pressing <kbd>SHIFT+S</kbd> and selecting *Cursor to Selected*.
[image]

Delete the vertex pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and selecting *Vertices* in the drop-down menu that appears.
[image]

Select the loop of the hole holding <kbd>ALT</kbd> and clicking on an edge of the loop.
[image]

Extrude it pressing <kbd>E</kbd> moving it a little bit and pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or the left mouse button.
[image]

Press <kbd>SHIFT+S</kbd> and select *Selection to Cursor* to move all these vertices on the cursor.
[image]
[image]

Repeat for the other pole vertex.

Result:
[image]

Comment: with the second solution there is actually a "invisible" hole right?

Comment: Exactly! If you have just to render that's not a problem, If you need to print than the first solution is better.

Comment: An alternative to get this result is start from a grid https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053/15543  (good for equirectangular UV maps)