# Plane to sphere - Strange shading with image texture

Tags: texturing, image

I created plane to sphere animation following this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24053

[image]

But when I add the image texture there is strange shading

[image: plane to sphere with texture]

How to fix the issue.

Comment: What do your normals look like?  (Overlays > Face Orientation)

Comment: maybe in the Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode, make sure that it is set to Opaque? Or please pack your image and share your file

Comment: @moonboots Thank you very much! The problem was as you said the blend mode : Alpha clip. Setting it to opeque fixed the issue. If you would put your comment as answer, I could mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the *Material panel > Settings > Blend Mode*, switch from *Alpha Blend* to *Opaque*.