# Uv Sphere Unwrap Perfect Square

Tags: animation, uv

Hello all i'm trying to do is get this sphere [image]

to be unwrapped as a perfect square to fit into the image i've been playing around with the uv settings can't seem to figure it out if anyone here knows how to do that please let me know thanks.

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Comment: nope i read that already didn't help also don't mark my post negative quit judging stuff so fast young man thanks have a good day

Comment: @WakaFlocka - I'm really curious what about the first post didn't help.  It's exactly what you're asking for isn't it?  If not, please add more info.

Comment: @WakaFlocka Please don't dismiss those that are trying to help you without explaining what didn't work.

Answer (score 11):

I personally like to think of this backwards

[image]

see [this link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053) or [this other one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13927/1853) that mean starting with an unwrapped plane and making a sphere out of it, to avoid using a UVsphere and the triangle fans at the poles.

But if you want to use a UVsphere here's an alternative:

In edit mode go to front back or a side view, chose an edge loop and mark a seam.

Switch to face selection and choose a face adjacent to the seam, that will make it the "active face".

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect everything and press <kbd>A</kbd> again to select all. You will see that the previously selected face is still the active face.

Press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap, and choose "follow active quads" and then press on OK using the default values

[image]

That will give you a perfect grid UV map, but the map will be much larger than the UV space.

[image]

you can scale it down to fit within the image you want to use.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ok now i get an error http://puu.sh/wNlDW/82d38a89ca.jpg why is this happening exactly?

Comment: that is a different question, please ask in a different post.

Comment: no i did what u posted mark seam select face unwrap follow active quads with default settings and i get that error http://puu.sh/wNlDW/82d38a89ca.jpg this is from this post

Comment: great answer, but my sphere is made of triangles, so I can't follow active quads. If only there was an option to follow active triangles.

Comment: @SeanBradley Please use the ask question link at the top of the page.

Answer (score 8):

I'm putting this here for completeness because I haven't seen it on BSE.  You can also use the ***Sphere Projection*** option in the Unwrap menu.

[image]

Then in the ***Tool Shelf*** set the ***Direction*** to ***Align to Object***:

[image]

Comment: It works for me. not only spherical but also irregular sphere shapes as well. Thanks