# How to uv unwrap a plane

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[Morph targets: A sphere shape turning into a cylindrical unwrapped sphere shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/morph-targets-a-sphere-shape-turning-into-a-cylindrical-unwrapped-sphere-shape/13927#13927)

This tutorial shows how to transform a plane into a sphere. However, it mentions UV unwrapping the plane. how am I supposed to do this?

Comment: UV unwrapping allows you to put a texture on your mesh, I guess if you use the method described in your link, i.e. folding a simple plane, you just need a basic unwrap, meaning U > Unwrap, but maybe describe your project more in details?

Comment: just explain how to do what he does in the image following "unwrap by pressing U". before that, he subdivided once, meaning the plane became four squares what is he doing in the unwrap image? also, Iam am using the accepted answer on the page.

Comment: what does change to face selection mean?

Comment: @cegaton: "Maybe that person will eventually learn how to write proper answers", could you please precise what you mean? You actually don't need to use Project from view, a simple Unwrap will work - and no need for face selection either...

Comment: oh ok didn't understand   ;)  Anyway, I think we lack informations about what Rishab wants

Comment: Maybe related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/uv-sphere-unwrap-perfect-square/84859#84859