# Applying decal to sphere

Tags: animation, shrinkwrap

I am trying to add a decal to a sphere. This question has been asked before, but the answers aren't really helpful.  Is there a way that I can apply an Image plane to a sphere using the shrink-wrap modifier, and be able to still animate it on the sphere? I have already tried subdividing the image, and using the shrinkwrap mod., but the result is a distorted image.
[image: Sphere decal]

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you intend to animate the decal on the sphere?  Have you tried already and failed, is there a problem you have encountered?

Comment: Yes. I tried subdividing the plane, and applying the Shrinkwrap modifier, but the decal becomes distorted when I do so.

Comment: It would be helpful to add that information into your question, and also link to the other questions that you found unhelpful so that others reading the question have the same info.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84854/uv-sphere-unwrap-perfect-square/84859#84859

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate morphing a rectangular plane into a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere)

Comment: No, sadly. What I am trying to animate is the image texture on the surface of the sphere.

Comment: Can you draw a sketch of desire result? And what kind of animation you mean? Or can you share some googled referenc that looks similar to your idea, t I can't get the image of what is your goal. BTW any plane image will be distorted in some way on sphere shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your help and time. I actually found the answer to my question on my own. The way to animate the image on the sphere. (Going around the sphere as I intended) is to add a multi-res to the sphere, and to apply the shrink-wrap mod to the plane. Then I set the plane's origin to the center of the sphere so that the image can be moved around the sphere. It will look like it is on the sphere though, and thus solves my problem.[image]

Comment: How to avoid the image from casting shadows on the sphere, if you take a closer look at the edge you will find the shadow