# Accurate wrapping of plane around cylinder

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to model a pill bottle with very precise dimensions. I've created both the bottle and the label correctly sized in inches. I'm trying to wrap the label around the bottle in a realistic manner so it doesn't distort. I can't find a method that works. I tried using the shrink wrap modifier, the curve modifier and the simple deform modifier (nothing 'simple' about that!). I've managed to get the label to wrap around the surface of the bottle with all three methods, but the image on the label (not shown) is always distorted, and none of the methods seem very intuitive. I'm sure there must be an easier way that I've managed to overlook. Any ideas?

UPDATE : Additional images show the geometry of the label and the bottle with and without the shrinkwrap modifier applied. I've tried all the different combinations of Wrap Method and Snap Mode, but the image on the label still distorts (image not shown). Circumference of the bottle is about 7.5" and the label is 7.25" wide, so it should warp around the bottle with about a 0.25" gap between the label ends.

[image: pill-bottle]

[image: wireframe]

[image: shrinkwrap applied]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying decal to sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160306/applying-decal-to-sphere)

Comment: sounds like you don't have enough geometry on the plane to support the curvature of the bottle.  Can you show a screenshot of the plane wrapped around the bottle with the shrinkwrap technique in wireframe mode, along with the modifier settings for the shrinkwrap?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Emir. I may be doing something wrong, but I followed the advice on that thread and the label still got distorted instead of maintaining it's original width (7.25").

Comment: Does the folling answer help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40970/31447

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within the limitations of the approximation of curves by straight-line segments, and floating-point error in trig. and other functions, *Simple Deform > Bend* should not change the length of the plane passing through its origin.

The circumference of the bottle is `pi*2.39`,  = `7.5084`. The Label must be bent through `7.25 / 7.5084` of a circle: `347.61` degrees.

If (using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> snapping) you place a world-aligned Empty on the  end of the front-facing radius of your bottle, and place the label, with its origin at its centre, at the same point, then giving the label a *Simple Deform > Bend* through that angle, with the Empty as origin, should give an exact wrap:

[image]

There will be Z-fighting, so you may have to give the label a very slight *Solidify* or *Displace* modification to bring it outside the bottle's surface.

If the label's own axes are conveniently aligned, you could forget the Empty.. but I find it less bother always to use *Simple Deform* with an Empty, around the Empty's Z, which makes the deforming axis, X.