# Bug applying Simple Deform Modifier as Shape Key?

Tags: modifiers, shape-keys

I create an animation with a plane is transforming to a sphere by using the method describing by @leon-cheung in [this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere).

[image]

I want to apply the two modifiers (Bend in Simple Deform) as shape key but the result is not indentic.

[image]

It seems that it is the second modifier which is the problem.

There are no problem if I use only one modifier with an angle less than 180°.

Is there a way to have the same result (animation transforming plane to sphere ) by using shape keys?

This is the file about my question :

[image]

Comment: A [shape key](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/shape_keys/shape_keys_panel.html) holds a vertex's distance relative to the base position. The second shape key is moving vertices a distance from the base not from the second shapekeys position. You can make the second shape use the first as it's base. Above value, you have a relative option, try disabling this so that a shapekey uses absolute positions. I expect that would lead to one key being modifier one and one shapekey being a combination of both deforms.

Comment: thank you @sambler for your help but I can't obtain a sphere with this method . It is like as to obtain a sphere we 'll have to Apply these two Modifiers at the same time but it is not possible !

Comment: Does the .blend linked in that answer work for you?

Comment: @gandalf3  I don't understand,  what answer are you referring to? Is it this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ojv5B6Lb-3TjhLUWc0eTlHMXc ? If so that yes this file works for me.  I added a file where there is my problem : https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4588/

Comment: Try creating the sphere like this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/13927/1853

Comment: Thank you @cegaton , this method works ,it  is not as good as by using modifier but it works ! If anybody comes up with something better, I'd be very happy to know this method !

Comment: There is a  solution by using 2 (or more for best results)  shapekeys named "Join as shape" between the first plane with modifiers and a second plane copy of the first without modifier. And then modify the F-curves in Graph Editor to have a smooth transition. You can see this solution [here](https://developer.blender.org/T54155).