# Parametric design for pen adapter for 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

I have this model I created for a little kid who has problems in their hands (muscular and/or skeletal). I was thinking that it would be awesome to release the design so anyone with this problems can 3d print it fairly cheap. I guess that the size of the model would be proportional to the size of the hand, but as you can imaging the hole for the pen will remain the same.

I am still prototyping the model and it´s not the final version, but I am already thinking about this part.

Some pics of the process so you can have an idea.
[image]
[image]
[image]

First picture, from left to right: v.1a @ 105%, v.1a @ 100%, v.2a @ 105%,v.2 @ 100%

Last picture is the newest version (v.2a, yellow ones were too big but sort of ok for my big hand to test and improve.

Thanks everybody in advance

EDIT: I attached everything [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1p9Tp6fflMt92cxRjUmcT1FG8P_l36thy?usp=sharing):

Comment: Can you upload a model to test ideas on?

Comment: Done, and thank you! I am a newbie, so don´t be too harsh on me :).

Comment: Hi. I'm not really sure what your question is.

Comment: Your question is in  the the category of questions of when a person talks about a medical problem or remedies for medical problems.  I have seen questions get quite a few points for the category.   Such a category is often immune to being closed for being off topic.  You writing above does not really seem to be about Blender.  It seems to be about product development.   I am no expert yet ... is there not a website for such ideas ... GoFundMe or Shark Tank or YooToob or something of that sort.  First of all I will not vote to close the question. (Running out of comment space so) The second of

Comment: Second of all. Your idea might help me since I really do not use a pen or pencil enough.  Will your product appear soon in drugstores or discount stores? Looks really comfy.  Do you have a turquoise color available?  What is the MSRP?

Comment: Oh I almost forgot.  I had to upvote you . Merci mille fois.

Comment: Lol? I´ve attached the blender files, I am doing this for free in my free time, I´ll release all this...

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem to be:
"How do I make this model parametric, so people don't need to change vertices in order to adapt it to their physiology"

Here I have a few pointers:

1. The question of the pen is probably the easiest solution: Create a mesh for a pen and use a boolien modifier to create the hole. Each grip can be scaled but the hole for the pencil will remain the same size.
2. Unless blender implements an node based modelling toolkit in the near future, your toolkit in order of ease to use consists of:

   - shape-keys [Morph targets: A sphere shape turning into a cylindrical unwrapped sphere shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/morph-targets-a-sphere-shape-turning-into-a-cylindrical-unwrapped-sphere-shape?noredirect=1&lq=1)
   - boolean modifiers
   - scripts

Comment: There already is a node based procedural modeling kit, it's called Sverchok, and it's powerful as heck ☺️

Comment: Thank you, yes, my question was indeed "How do I make this model parametric". You guys gave me a bunch of ideas that i´ll have to explore and I have limited time, so thank you again I´ll  try to me be more clear in the future with my questions.