# pipe which has non-uniform cross-section

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I want to create a shape like a pipe, like below image and blend file.

I created the mesh below in Houdini, but I could deal with it only in simple case, and I couldn't improve it any more in Houdini. So I am trying blender.

.blend file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51832

[image]

What "non-uniform cross-section" means both 1. and 2.

1. scaling independently on each axis of cross section
2. changing the cross section shape.

I tested the below but I have trouble in all of them.

- I can't use "Curve Bevel Function"
  ([Make a 3D tube with a Bézier curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8683/make-a-3d-tube-with-a-b%C3%A9zier-curve), [Curve Bevel function, scale?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale))
  because this can use only one cross section. Even if I use Bevel Object, Alt+S, Proportional Editing and Taper Object, We can't use multiple different cross section shapes and We can't scale independently on each axis of cross section.
- I also tried vertex group + proportional editing
  ([Is it possible to use proportional editing without affecting or hiding nearby vertices](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21577/is-it-possible-to-use-proportional-editing-without-affecting-or-hiding-nearby-ve))
  but failed.
- I tried addons https://blendermarket.com/products/bezier-mesh-shaper and
  https://github.com/mifth/mifthtools/wiki/Mira-Tools#curve-stretch-tool.
  These may be solution, but I have trouble when pipe length is long like this case.

Could you tell me effective way to create a pipe which has non-uniform cross-section ?

I don't think my question is duplicate of [Curve Bevel function, scale?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/curve-bevel-function-scale) because my question emphasises the non-uniform cross section and mentioned that Curve Bevel function doesn't allow us to use non-uniform cross section.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. You have a pipe with a non-uniform cross section in that file. I assume it isn't the kind of non-uniform that you want. Are you trying to blend from a square cross section to a circle, or something like that?

Comment: sorry for confusing.

I created this shape by procedural modeling in Houdini.
But  in Houdini,  I have difficulty in creating more complex  non-uniform cross-section. For example,  rotating cross section,  or snapping the cap to another shape, and blend cross sections as you say.

So I want to create it in direct modeling, if possible.

Comment: so yes, it is one  kind of non-uniform that I want. 

The reason why I want to know how to create this in blender is  I think that blender may allow me to create more shape which I couldn't create in houdini

Comment: Can you sketch roughly what kind of object it is that you want to make in the end?

Comment: Thanks for reopening.
I am bad at sketch, so I paste the image of the shape what I want create.
[https://imgur.com/a/zSQpHMD](https://imgur.com/a/zSQpHMD) 
This is polygon hair. I think this shape made up from some of pipes, which each has non uniform cross section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can certainly extrude a cross section along a curve and rotate that cross section, change its size and change the end cap.

Try using a curve modifier with an array modifier and change the start/end caps:

[image]

You can also experiment with bevel curves and tapers:

[image]

In the old days we used to be able to transition between cross sections by using dupliframes to create multiple copies of a mesh along a curve at frame intervals (e.g. one every 10 frames) and then loft them together. Something like this: [old Blenderartists thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-loft-if-blender-can-do-it-at-all/396759/10) but I'm not sure how you do that now. Maybe using the animation nodes add on. It's a starting point at least.

Hopefully somebody will have a better answer for you, but in the meantime this gives you something to work with.

Comment: I'm interested in lofting, too .. couldn't see the DupliFrames method in the your BA link? @batFINGER gave a nice answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/122232/35559). What would be really nice would be a revival / rewrite of the bSurfaces add-on, which, among other things, enabled lofting between curves / gpencil of arbitrary resolution.

Comment: You can use dupliframes along these lines using 2.79: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGfFiakg6Z8 (basically add path curve, add cross section object, ctrl-p to make object follow path, panel:Object/Duplication/Frames untick Speed, ctrl-shift-a to make duplicates real). The trick is how to join the resulting cross sections manually, i.e. lofting, which is where I can't help you.